# willSelectRowAtIndexPath Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How do you add a second section (SECOND_SECTION) here to be excluded from selection when editing?

```
 (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSIndexPath *rowToSelect = indexPath;
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    BOOL isEditing = self.editing;
    // If editing, don't allow notes to be selected
    // Not editing: Only allow notes to be selected
    if ((isEditing && section == ONE_SECTION) || (!isEditing && section != ONE_SECTION)) {
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  rowToSelect = nil;

    }

 return rowToSelect;
}
```

it s being driving me nuts...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since we know you’re concerned with editing behavior, look at the part that begins with `if ((isEditing && …`. What comes after that will be evaluated only in editing mode. So, to add another section, you could change it like so:

```
    if ((isEditing && (section == ONE_SECTION || section == SECOND_SECTION)) || (!isEditing && section != ONE_SECTION)) {
```

Comment: this is what i tried: if ((isEditing && (section == NOTES_SECTION || section == PRINT_SECTION)) || (!isEditing && (section != NOTES_SECTION || section != PRINT_SECTION))) {

Comment: `(section != NOTES_SECTION || section != PRINT_SECTION)` will *always* return true. You probably want `(section != NOTES_SECTION && section != PRINT_SECTION)`.